# Convert select in postgress to return array instead of string (just for one row)

Tags: json, postgresql

I have objects in postgres db in one column:

```
{"svc": {"times": [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]}}
{"svc": {"times": [1.6, 2.3, 5.5]}}
...
```

And with select query:

```
SELECT services->'svc'->>'times'
```

I get rows with strings:

```
"[1.2, 1.3, 1.4]"
"[1.6, 2.3, 5.5]"
```

or with  `SELECT json_agg(services->'svc'->>'times')`:

```
["[1.2, 1.3, 1.4]", "[1.6, 2.3, 5.5]"]
```

But I need an arrays (one array will be good as well):

```
[1.2, 1.3, 1.4]
[1.6, 2.3, 5.5]
```

So I can process it with python script (but I want to get array directly from db). i.e.

```
rows = select_result
my_list = []
for row in rows:
    my_list.extend(row)
```

Tried lot of pg functions (split, array) for that but nothing woks well. Should I change type of data stored to achieve this by default?

Comment: You can try [`ast.literal_eval`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1894296/4985099)

Comment: Are you having problems with the postgres part or the python part?  If you want the times array as a Postgres array - use `->`. `SELECT '{"svc": {"times": [1.2, 1.3, 1.4]}}'::json->'svc'->'times';`

Comment: @madflow the double `>>` make me confused - I got nice output when using tool for db queries but for code it made me looking for some wierd solution:) Thanks and post the answer - I will upvote!